# Forward declaration causing problems in header file

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to learn about link lists and nodes and I don't understand this error I get within my Node struct. This is the code that worked perfectly fine, without a forward declaration in the header

```
#ifndef SENTENCE_H
#define SENTENCE_H

#include"word.h"

class Sentence{
    public:
        struct Node{
            Word data;
            Node * next;
        };
            //etc
#endif // SENTENCE_H
```

but then I had to add function prototypes that required me to change this to

```
#ifndef SENTENCE_H
#define SENTENCE_H

class Sentence;

#include"paragraph.h"
#include"word.h"

class Sentence{
    public:
        struct Node{
            Word data;
            Node * next;
        };
        //etc, etc
```

now when I try to compile this I get an error: field 'data' has incomplete type. If I comment out the struct everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? I believe this is the correct way to make a node is it not? As in a Sentence is a linked list of Nodes with Words in them. Thus the 'data' is a Word, and next is a pointer to a Node. The Word type should be acceptable because of the include statement, I have no problem with the function prototype "Word first();" in the etc part of the code, so why does it tell me that 'data' has an incomplete type?

Comment: Why are you forward declaring Sentence in it's own header file?

Comment: The culprit is obviously `Word`. But you don't show how `Word` is declared. How is it declared?

Comment: @laser_wizard because my paragraph.h needs to know about a Sentence class

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball tells me that your problem has nothing to do with forward declaration and everything to do with circular header inclusion. The same ball tells me that at some point `word.h` began to include `sentence.h` directly or indirectly. Now, since your `sentence.h` includes `word.h` as well, that produced circular inclusion loop.

Circular inclusion does not ever achieve anything, besides weird "unexplainable" compilation errors.